# force MS VS2010 to rebuild one cpp-file on every build

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

In one cpp-file I use the `__DATE__` macro to get the compile-date.

It gives me the date of the last compile **of that file**. But as the file is not changed very often, the date is old in most cases, sometimes several months.

What I actually want is the date of the last build **of the project**.

Is there an setting to force VS2010 to rebuild that single cpp-file on every compile of the project?
Regardless of changes in the file?

The only way I found until now is to modify the file or delete the created obj-file by an script before the build, I would prefer an solution inside VS if that is possible.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could probably add a `Pre-Build Step` that `touch` (see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51435/windows-version-of-the-unix-touch-command)) the file?

To add a `Pre-Build Step`, open your `Project Properties`, then `Configuration Properties > Build Events > Pre-Build Event` then add the command line you want to have executed in `Command Line`.

Following the suggestion from Amitd, apparently you can also `touch` the file using PowerShell, see [this](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-touch.html) for explanations.

As suggested by Adrian McCarthy in the comments below, deleting the `.obj` file would be preferable in the context where source control is used and you want to keep the `.cpp` `read-only`. Using the "macros" exposed by Visual Studio, deleting them can be made easy:

```
del $(TargetDir)sourcefile.obj
```

Quoted from Cheers and hth. - Alf as another way to achieve this

```
nmake (bundled with Visual Studio and the SDK) option /t does a touch, it was once the conventional way to do this for Windows programmers.
```

Comment: This would probably be a bit more complicated as, depending on your configuration, the .obj could be output at different places

Comment: There is no touch on windows, but your answer and google led me to the fact that "copy /b Source+,," has the same effect in windows, so that should work.

Comment: @MacGucky that's why I linked the SO thread, you would need to install `unixutils` to have touch or as the 2nd answer suggests `copy /b filename.ext +,,`

Comment: also u can use Powershell: C:\> powershell  (ls your-file-name-here).LastWriteTime = Get-Date

Comment: @emartel: ups - didn't follow the link, as I knew that Windows has no touch. But anyhow - I changed my project and it works as expected. Thank you.

Comment: I prefer deleting the object file, as it allows the source file to remain read-only if you're using source control.  The object file location may indeed depend on the configuration, but the macros make that simple to handle, e.g., `del $(TargetDir)datefile.obj`.

Comment: @MakGucky: `nmake` (bundled with Visual Studio and the SDK) option `/t` does a touch, it was once the conventional way to do this for Windows programmers.

Comment: @emartel: no one does not need to install nix utilities to have a touch command, just use `nmake` option `/t`.

Comment: $(IntDir) is probably preferable to $(TargetDir).  Also, for some Studio versions the pre-build step will not be invoked if the project's dependencies do not require recompilation, so make it a post-build step instead.

Comment: I couldn't get the copy command to actually update the timestamp, so I used the deleting the obj file technique.  The path for me, though, was $(IntDir)sourcefile.obj.

Comment: How to use nmake with /t, add them to the pre-build event too?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following pre-build step, were you simply touch the date stamp of the file. The `+,,` is a special flag to the `copy` command, telling it to update the timestamp of the file:

```
copy file.cpp +,,
```

Answer (score 1):

As [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13497382/force-ms-vs2010-to-rebuild-one-cpp-file-on-every-build/53152782#comment18472888_13497519) by Adrian McCarthy, you can simply delete the object file every time you build the project.

Therefore, create a pre-build event invoking the `del` command. According to [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/c02as0cs.aspx), you can use the `$(IntDir)` macro to refer to the directory wher the object file is stored (you should not use the `$(TargetDir)` macro).

I had issues with the return code of the command (error `MSB3073`), therefore I changed the command to always exit with `0`.

```
del $(IntDir)datefile.obj & exit 0
```

Create this build event in the project configuration, under *Configuration Properties / Build Events*.