# How can I make sure that a file is compiled on every build n msvc?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a source file that saves date and time of build as follow:

```
const std::string buildTimestamp() {
     return "Built on " + std::string(__DATE__) +  " at " + std::string(__TIME__);
}
```

But it only works if it is compiled on every build. How can I make sure that it is compiled on every build (it is not changing between builds so msvc doesn't see it as changed and hence doesn't compile it)

Is there any better way to add date/time of build to a compiled c++ code?

Comment: Touch the source in a pre-build step of the project.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13497382/force-ms-vs2010-to-rebuild-one-cpp-file-on-every-build

Comment: Write the string as `return std::string("Built on "__DATE__" at "__TIME__);`